# Is there a good way to import unsorted data into QuestDB in bulk?

Tags: questdb

I have a 100GB data file with sensor readings spanning a few weeks. The timestamps are **not in strict chronological order** and I'd like to bulk load the data into QuestDB. The order is not completely random, but there is a deviation of up to three minutes of lateness where some rows are 3 minutes late.
Is there an efficient way to do bulk loading like this and ensure that the data is ordered chronologically at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is in a 3-step phase

1. Import the unordered dataset, you can do this via curl:

   ```sh
   curl -F data=@unordered-data.csv 'http://localhost:9000/imp'
   ```
2. Create a table with the schema of the imported data and apply a partitioning
   strategy. The
   `timestamp` column may be cast as a `timestamp` if auto detection of the timestamp failed:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE ordered AS (
   SELECT
     cast(timestamp AS timestamp) timestamp,
     col1,
     col2
   FROM 'unordered-data.csv' WHERE 1 != 1
   ) timestamp(timestamp) PARTITION BY DAY;
   ```
3. Insert the unordered records into the partitioned table and provide a `lag`
   and `batch` size:

   ```sql
   INSERT batch 100000 lag 180000000 INTO ordered
   SELECT
     cast(timestamp AS timestamp) timestamp,
     col1,
     col2
   FROM 'unordered-data.csv';
   ```

To confirm that the table is ordered, the `isOrdered()` function may be used:

```sql
select isOrdered(timestamp) from ordered
```

| isOrdered |
| --- |
| true |

There is more info on loading data in this way on the [CSV import documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/guides/importing-data#large-datasets-with-out-of-order-data)

- `lag` can be about 3 minutes in your case, it's the expected lateness of records
- `batch` is the number of records to batch process at one time